# Schtasks.exe gives Access Denied error when trying to access remote computer using a local admin account

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

When I execute `schtasks /query /s serverName /u serverName\user /p password` I get an `Access is denied` error. `serverName\user` is in the Administrators group on server.

Any ideas?

Comment: So many things can go wrong here. Could you elaborate more how you are executing this program? Is schtasks run on your PC? Do you start it in elevated mode? Do you run it in a command prompt? Do you run it in a script? Are you sure you did not misspell the password? Did you check that the user has "Logon as batch job"-rights? Why don't you use the task scheduler console? On which OS are you running the command? Do you have any logfiles that contain more information than "access denied" (Security Log on server, maybe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Windows Firewall is off or not blocking.

Comment: Yeah...I found that out for this problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/241825/schtasks-cant-administer-remote-tasks

Answer (score 0):

This answer my help: [unable to schedule a task (access denied)](https://serverfault.com/questions/36588/unable-to-schedule-a-task-access-denied).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that answer only applies to 2k3/2k/xp.